# Django Updateview can't save data and redirect

Tags: django, django-views

**template**

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="_save" />
</form>
```

**form**

```
class LabelUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
        model = models.SlPannelli
        fields = '__all__'
```

**view**

```
class LabelUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = models.SlPannelli
    exclude=()
    fields = '__all__'
#    form_class = LabelUpdateForm  

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super(LabelUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
        return TemplateResponse(self.request, self.template_name, locals())
```

**urls**

```
url(r'^labelch/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.LabelUpdateView.as_view(), name='label_update'),
```

I can see the loaded data for update, but when hit Update button keep getting redirectedto "labelch/" page and can't save updated data.

```
Vedi Informazioni
Funzione View   Argomenti   Parole chiave   Nome URL
<nessuna view>
u'None'
u'None'
None
Cookies
Variabile   Valore
'cookieconsent_dismissed'
'yes'
'csrftoken'
'vUdhIR42Z4c3aCgbeVugQidDHoa8gFby'
'djdt'
'hide'
'sessionid'
'f9957eaw537wg6v8xi069dqq5cqyrvxd'
Dati di sessione
Variabile   Valore
u'_auth_user_backend'
u'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
u'_auth_user_hash'
u'55822a00e348b79b5cd03be74b185995766915a7'
u'_auth_user_id'
u'1'
Nessun dato in GET
Dati POST
Variabile   Valore
u'_save'
[u'Update']
u'csrfmiddlewaretoken'
[u'vUdhIR42Z4c3aCgbeVugQidDHoa8gFby', u'vUdhIR42Z4c3aCgbeVugQidDHoa8gFby']
u'note'
[u'']
u'tipo'
[u'S2']
```

this is the output of **REQUEST** django debug tolbar

Comment: - why there's a second return on form_valid(self, form) ? (btw, never use the locals() trick, some day you'll debug for hours something unexplicable, trust me)  - are you sure the data is valid ? try to override form_invalid and print the errors, maybe there are some errors and your template is not showing them.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/labelch$', views.LabelUpdateView.as_view(), name='label_update'),
```

can't understand why but changing the order for the pk in the URL solved all problems!

@simone thanks for advices, will keep in mind in future!